# How can I do 64 bit division on linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I want the do the following code on linux kernel (32 bit processor):

```
#define UQ64 long long int
#define UI32 long int

UQ64 qTimeStamp;
UQ64 qSeconds;
UI32 uTimeStampRes;

qTimeStamp = num1;
uTimeStampRes = num2;

// 64 division !
qSeconds = qTimeStamp / uTimeStampRes;
```

There is an algorithm to calculate the 64 division ?
Thanks.

Comment: The code you posted does not work?

Comment: Is impossible to divide 64 bit on linux kernel that works on 32 bit processor. @KamilCuk

Comment: It's possible to divide any bit number using a compiler on a machine which supports that kind of operations. gcc on a 32-bit machine is conforming to C standard, which means it supports 64-bit operations (using `long long int` type which is **at least** 64-bit long). You can divide 64-bit numbers on 8-bit architecture providing your compiler can generate proper code. As a side note, gcc as an extension supports `__int128` type (and operations)

Comment: Och, I start doubting myself, or kernel space is different and I am [wrong](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/include/asm/div64.h#L22) ?

Comment: @KamilCuk it only the attempt to micro optimize the code and do not use the library functions. Nothing else.

Comment: You can use the functions provided by `#include <linux/math64.h>` to do 64-bit division.

Comment: Note that `long int` will be 64-bit on a 64-bit kernel. A normal `int` is better if you really want a 32-bit integer in the kernel. Also, your naming convention of beginning your typenames with `U` for *signed* types is confusing!

Comment: @TobySpeight I think every kernel programmer has probably been caught out by 64-bit division in the Linux kernel at some point. The problems don't appear until you build for a 32-bit kernel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The GCC C compiler generates code that calls functions in the libgcc library to implement the `/` and `%` operations with 64-bit operands on 32-bit CPUs.  However, the Linux kernel is **not** linked against the libgcc library, so such code will fail to link when building code for a 32-bit Linux kernel.  (When building an external kernel module, the problem may not be apparent until you try and dynamically load the module into the running kernel.)

Originally, the Linux kernel only had the `do_div(n,base)` macro defined by `#include <asm/div64.h>`.  The usage of this macro is unusual because it modifies its first argument *in place* to become the quotient resulting from the division, and yields (returns) the remainder from the division as its result.  This was done for code efficiency reasons but is a bit of a pain to use.  Also, it only supports division of a 64-bit unsigned dividend by a 32-bit divisor.

Linux kernel version 2.6.22 introduced the `#include <linux/math64.h>` header, which defines a set of functions which is more comprehensive than the old `do_div(n,base)` macro and is easier to use because they behave like normal C functions.

The functions declared by `#include <linux/math64.h>` for 64-bit division are listed below.  Except where indicated, all of these have been available since kernel version 2.6.26.

One of the functions listed below in *`italics`* does not exist yet as of kernel version 4.18-rc8.  Who knows if it will ever be implemented?  (Some other functions declared by the header file related to multiply and shift operations in later kernel versions have been omitted below.)

- `u64 div_u64(u64 dividend, u32 divisor)` — unsigned division of 64-bit dividend by 32-bit divisor.
- `s64 div_s64(s64 dividend, s32 divisor)` — signed division of 64-bit dividend by 32-bit divisor.
- `u64 div_u64_rem(u64 dividend, u32 divisor, u32 *remainder)` — unsigned division of 64-bit dividend by 32-bit divisor with remainder.
- `s64 div_s64_rem(s64 dividend, s32 divisor, s32 *remainder)` — signed division of 64-bit dividend by 32-bit divisor with remainder.
- `u64 div64_u64(u64 dividend, u64 divisor)` — unsigned division of 64-bit dividend by 64-bit divisor.
- `s64 div64_s64(s64 dividend, s64 divisor)` — **(since 2.6.37)** signed division of 64-bit dividend by 64-bit divisor.
- `u64 div64_u64_rem(u64 dividend, u64 divisor, u64 *remainder)` — **(since 3.12.0)** unsigned division of 64-bit dividend by 64-bit divisor with remainder.
- *`s64 div64_s64_rem(s64 dividend, s64 divisor, s64 *remainder)`* — **(does not exist yet as of 4.18-rc8)** signed division of 64-bit dividend by 64-bit divisor with remainder.
- `div64_long(x,y)` — **(since 3.4.0)** macro to do signed division of a 64-bit dividend by a `long int` divisor (which is 32-bit or 64 bit, depending on the architecture).
- `div64_ul(x,y)` — **(since 3.10.0)** macro to do unsigned division of a 64-bit dividend by an `unsigned long int` divisor (which is 32-bit or 64-bit, depending on the architecture).
- `u32 iter_div_u64_rem(u64 dividend, u32 divisor, u64 *remainder)` — unsigned division of 64-bit division by 32-bit divisor by repeated subtraction of divisor from dividend, with remainder (may be faster than regular division if the dividend is not expected to be much bigger than the divisor).

Answer (score 2):

You can divide any size numbers on any bits computer.  The only difference is the way the division is done. On a processor which handles 64 bit integers natively, it will be one machine code instruction (I do not know any 64bit processor without hardware division). On processors with narrower registers it will be translated to a series of machine code instructions or a call to a library function dividing those 64-bit numbers:

```
uint64_t foo(uint64_t x, uint64_t y)
{
    return x/y;
}
```

On amd64 instruction set:

```asm
        mov     rax, rdi
        xor     edx, edx
        div     rsi
        ret
```

On ia32 instrtuction set:

```asm
sub     esp, 12
push    DWORD PTR [esp+28]
push    DWORD PTR [esp+28]
push    DWORD PTR [esp+28]
push    DWORD PTR [esp+28]
call    __udivdi3
add     esp, 28
ret
```

Comment: But `__udivdi3` does not exist in the Linux kernel. In the Linux kernel, your `foo` could be replaced with `div64_u64` defined by `#include <linux/math64.h>`.

Comment: @IanAbbott it is only to ilustrate the difference single machine instruction vs function call.

Comment: Well as long as you make it clear that your `foo` function as written is unsuitable for use in the Linux kernel.